# hibernate column unique property not changing

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc

Is there any way to change the column property from `unique=true` to `unique=false` without dropping the table?

Now I am stuck in the situation where tables has been created earlier and these table are containing data too. When I changed `unique=true` to `unique=false` it doesn't making any changes in table.

Comment: You'll need to make the changes manually in the database. It would be terrible if Hibernate modified the schema every time you make a change to an entity. If you've never used a database (using Hibernate doesn't count), you'll be learning a lot of new things too!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this thing in the database. Suppose I have a table Person with Person_name having a unique constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE Person
DROP INDEX Person_name;

or

ALTER TABLE Persons
DROP CONSTRAINT Person_name;
```

If you try to achieve the same thing using hibernate, hibernate will try to drop and create the table again, which you do not want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I don't know if you can allow yourself on database drop but you can try in your application properties file use:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

or

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

For more info:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Also if you know that you will have a lot of changes in database schema and you want to make it easy to work you should get familiar with 
https://www.liquibase.org/

Comment: Update only applies to schema changes, not constraints or such.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate won't update to implement constraints on the table because there is a possibility of having an error as the existing table might have inconsistencies.